# FlatList renderItem cannot read the state

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

My code crash when loading the FlatList because of the state of one variable is undefined, I am trying to see what's going on so print the value while loading the data, I see what I put on super.props

Note that I am nesting another FlatList inside the main one:

```
  export default class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    collapsed: true,
    }
  }

   componentDidMount() {
    this.apiCall();
   }

  renderItem({ item, index }) {
  const collapsed = this.state;
  return 
  <View style={styles.card}>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => {
      this.setState({ collapsed: !this.state.collapsed });
      }}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>
        {item.name.trim()}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <FlatList
    style={{paddingBottom: 20}}
    data={item.positions}
    numColumns={1}
    listKey={(item, index) => item.id}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (

      <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.collapsed} align="center">
        <Text style={styles.position} >{item.position.trim()}</Text>
      </Collapsible>

        )}/>
  </View>
  }

  render() {
  const resizeMode = 'cover';
  const collapsed = this.state;
  return (

    <Text>{this.state.collapsed.toString()}</Text>

    {this.state.loaded ?
    <Animatable.View easing='ease-out-circ'
    duration={1000} animation="fadeIn" >

    <FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
    removeClippedSubviews={true}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={32}
    initialNumToRender={64}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
    data={this.state.data}
    numColumns={2}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    listKey={(item, index) => item.id}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    style={styles.list}
    />

    </Animatable.View> 
    : null}
      );
    }
  }
```

The error I got after loading the data:

> TypeError : undefined is not an object ( evaluating
>   this3.state.collapsed )

As far as what I tried is setting undefined in `<Collapsible collapsed={undefined} align="center">` I can print the elements like expected but then the touchableOpacity don't work because of undefined.

Please someone help. Thanks

PS: Not sure if it works it gonna collapse all views or just the clicked one!

Comment: it definitely works, the opposite shows nothing tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `bind()` your `renderItem` method to access the `this.state`, but it's better to use your method as an arrow function to avoid these types of problem.
You can make your function as below, in this way your function accesses `this`:

```
renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
   ...
}
```

Comment: the state change but nothing happens, no collapse :( I also got this error: InputRange must be monotonically increasing 0

Comment: Use extraData={this.state. collapsed} prop for your FlatList.

Comment: man you're a genius, thanks so much, now all views collapse like I expected, this method did not solve my issue, thank you anyway for your help, also it works only first time, and btw it's so slow

Comment: Take a look at this doc, It can help you to improve the performance of your code. I hope it help you. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html